# Basic Set Theory and Functions, Injectivity of Inverse, Is this a mistake by the Professor?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

**The professor's original question follows.**
$f:A\rightarrow B$ and $|B| < |A|$.  Can you make any conclusions as to whether f is injective or surjective?  Can you make any conclusions as to whether $f^{-1}$ is injective or surjective?

**The professor's answer follows:**
f is not injective but might be surjective.
$f^{-1}$ is injective but not surjective.

**My Thinking**
I agree with the professor in all aspects except $f^{-1}$ is injective.
Intuitively, if f is injective then $f^{-1}$ is also injective.  Plus vice versa, the converse.  However, f is not injective.  The converse prevents $f^{-1}$ from being injective.  Where is the mistake?  Am I making a mistake or him?
Note: I'm familiar with the fact that the inverse might be merely a relation and not a function.

Comment: Are different definitions used for anything particularly the inverse which would change my answer?

Some relevant notes and context:
I'm actually a tutor.  The student is in Discrete Math.  I'm assuming the following definition for inverses.  Scroll down to definition of inverse.
https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/SUNY_Schenectady_County_Community_College/Discrete_Structures/06%3A_Functions/6.05%3A_Inverse_Functions

Comment: What do you mean when you say $f^{-1}$ exists?  That $f^{-1}$ is a function?  Because |B| < |A|, $f(x_1)=y=f(x_2)$ for some distinct$ x_1, x_2$. 
 So how can $f^{-1}$ be a function?

Can't $f{-1}$ be a relation?  Or does that notation apply exclusively to inverse functions?

Comment: However the inverse image always exists, for suitable domain restrictions in the non surjective case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said $f^{-1}$ is a symbol used for the pre-image of a function $f$. The existence of the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is linked to the concept of bijection, namely:
$$f \ \text{is a bijection} \iff f \ \text{has an inverse function} \ f^{-1}$$

In this case since $f:A\to B$ domain's cardinality is strictly grater of codomain $f$ could not be injective, so $f$ could be surjective or neither (for example constant functions). So in this case $f^{-1}$ isn't a function, let's have a look at an example
$$A =\{a,b,c,d\}, B =\{1,2,3\} \\
f(a)=1,f(b) = 2 , f(c)=f(d) = 3 $$

In this case $f^{-1}(3) = \{c,d\}$ and this fails the definition of a function, $f^{-1}$ could not be injective.

If we change the initial conditions $|A|< |B|$ in this case if $f$ is injective, $f^{-1}$ exist restricted to image of $f$ in $B$ and is injective. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the concurrence.  With only a Bachelor's, I'm usually a little bit uncomfortable correcting professors, but it appears warranted in this case.

Comment: No problem. I would like to point out that the reasoning also holds for infinite sets, even though I made up an example with finite sets

Comment: por supuesto = of course.